# Eclipse Color Themes - Groovy support? Explorer & Outline?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, themes

I've installed the Color Themes plugin and love it.  But... I have two issues I'm hoping someone can help with:

1. I want a dark theme, but they all fail to show Groovy code properly, essentially hiding some key characters like "}" and "=".  I did a search for Groovy on the themes site (which also claims Groovy support), but the results did not fix this.  Has anyone gotten a dark theme to show all of Groovy code properly?
2. I'd like more/all of Eclipse to follow the chosen theme.  It appears that it is only editors and not others such as Project Explorer, Outline, Console, ...  I assume this is how the Color Themes plugin works.  Has anyone gotten the other panes to follow the theme?

Thanks for any help!
Mark

Comment: (1) was fixed in answer below, but no answer for (2) yet - anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know much about the color themes plugin, but it is possible to go to Preferences -> Groovy -> Editor and select the operator color, as well as the other colors you want to change.

This feature is relatively new (since 2.1.2 of Groovy-Eclipse), and so the Color themes people may not have picked it up yet.  Best thing to do is to raise a bug on color themes to get this fixed.  They can send an email to the eclipse-plugin-user@groovy.codehaus.org mailing list if they need any details from Groovy-Eclipse to make this work.